Best Practices for BulkWrite Performance with Large Documents and Array Fields in a 2-Node
I'm using MongoDB's bulkWrite to update documents in batches of up to 500 updateOne operations. I'd like to ensure I'm following best practices for optimal performance. Here's some context about my collection and usage pattern:
Document Structure:
Each document contains 10 number fields
Each document contains an array with a maximum of 700 elements, each with 6 number fieldsAverage document size is around 10KB to 20KB
Indexing:
The _id field is indexed for efficient lookup and update by ID
Db Specifications:
RAM: 8 GB
Storage: 40 GB
CPU: 2 vCPUs
IOPS: 3000
Replica Set Configuration:
2-node replica set with:Node 1: 3 replicas (1 primary, 2 secondaries)Node 2: 2 replicas (1 primary, 1 secondary)
API Call Frequency:
I have an API where up to 1000 users between 6pm and 6:30pm, randomlyAverage of around 50-80 updates per second during this time period
I'd like to know if my current setup is optimal for performance. Are there any specific MongoDB configuration settings, indexing strategies, or query optimizations that I should consider to handle the large document size and array fields? Are there any potential bottlenecks in my replica set configuration that I should address?
Thanks in advance for your feedback!

What is a "2-node replica set with:Node 1: 3 replicas Node 2: 2 replicas"? A Replica Set can have only one PRIMARY, thus your statement does not make any sense.

I mean 2 clusters, not node

Means, you have two completely independent Mongo deployments?

No I have one deployment and I sharded that

So, you have a sharded cluster but with only one shard? Quite pointless, I would say. Apart from that, what do you mean by "for optimal performance"? What are you requirements? Do you have a performance problem? Document size of 10KB to 20KB is not "large". You need to be more specific.

I will rewrite quation.
